# How to give the user to create dynamic data?

Tags: c#, linq

I work in c# ,.Net 4.5.2 , WPF, Win7.

I have a big list of class A.
Class A contains 50~ different properties.
I want the user to be able to choose 2 properties from the class, in order to create a graph which the first property is the X value and the second is the Y value.
I've already created a user control that creates the graph, I only need to connect it to a list of Point.

The UI has 2 combo-box that the user can choose the X property and the Y property from the list.

I was thinking to do a big switch case in order to create each point, but i think there must be an easier way to create the points for the graph (LINQ maybe???)

Comment: Have you already filled the lists where the user can choose the properties? Is your problem the selection of the class properties or the drawing of the graph?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically choose which properties to get using Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998704/dynamically-choose-which-properties-to-get-using-linq)

Comment: what datatypes? double, string ?

Comment: I have all the data, but i need to create a new list that contains the 2 properties the user choose in a form of Point class. mostly double but i have some strings

Comment: Can the user choose the two properties randomly?

Comment: yes the user can choose the 2 properties as he wishes, even more the user can choose the same property for X and for Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a example (not yet tested)

```
   List<A> yourData = new List<A>();

        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(A).GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(double))         //do a sanity check if property is double
            .ToArray();


        //the user has to choose which PropertyInfo has to be taken... make a combobox or similar and use properties as binding source
        var propertyX = properties[3];
        var propertyY = properties[4];

        // create a list with the values
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        foreach (A item in yourData)
        {
            Point newPoint = new Point();

            newPoint.X =(double) propertyX.GetValue(item); 
            newPoint.Y = (double)propertyY.GetValue(item);
            points.Add(newPoint);
        }

        //now do something with you extracted data and have fun
```

Comment: @Mat, you can create a list of point in one line, without `foreach`, like this: `List<Point> points = yourData.Select(item => new Point {X =(double) propertyX.GetValue(item), Y = (double)propertyY.GetValue(item)}).ToList()`;

Comment: Thx I know. I prefer a non LINQ solution to show-case this stuff as I think it's more readable for beginners.